# Multiple Insert in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Dear friends first of all I paste my code then I will describe my issue. Please help.
VIEW

```
<?php echo form_open('my_index'); ?>
<label>Person1 </label><input type="text" name="input[]"><br><br>
<label>Person2 </label><input type="text" name="input[]"><br><br>
<label>Person3 </label><input type="text" name="input[]"><br><br>
<label>Person4 </label><input type="text" name="input[]"><br><br>
<button type="submit">Test</button>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

CONTROLLER

```
     public function my_index()
{
    $this->load->model('search/searchmodel');
    $r=$this->input->post('input');

    $this->searchmodel->myinsert($r);
}
```

MODEL

```
   public function myinsert($s){
$i=0;
foreach($s as $r){

    $this->db->insert('customer_order',array('customerName' => $r[$i]));
$i++;
}

}
```

My issue is as I run the code and enter data in the text-box as following: Person1= Jhon; Person2= Phillip; Person2= Mark; Person4= Jack. 
It gets inserted (in four rows, what I want)  but in the following way:
J, h, r, k . While I want to insert it as Jhon, Phillip, Mark, Jack (in four rows).

I don't know what is the mistake. Please someone help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model function is wrong. Try below, you no need to use `$r[$i]`.

```
public function myinsert($s){
  foreach($s as $r){    
    $this->db->insert('customer_order',array('customerName' => $r));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**In your model**

You should use **batch insert** `$this->db->insert_batch()` instead of `$this->db->insert()`.

```
public function myinsert($s){
  $data = [];

  $i=0;
  foreach($s as $r){
    $data[$i]['customerName'] = $r;
    $i++;
  }

  $this->db->insert_batch('customer_order', $data);

}
```

Here Read the [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data) for **batch insert**